# rely on java String copy on write

Tags: java, copy-on-write

My application creates a lot of instances of a class, say class A. All instance contains a string, and most of them contain the same String

```
class A {
   String myString;
}
```

I know that JVM makes "all equal strings" point to the same String that is stored just one time. If myString field of one of my A instances is overwritten, the reference to the original string is replaced by the reference to the new String value and all works as expected, that is as if each instance had a copy of the string all for itself. 
Is this behaviour required to a compliant JVM, or is it a sort of improvement of the jvm that may change from a jvm to another, or from version to version? 
**Another way to put the question**: when designing higly redundant (string based) data-structures, should one rely only on the copy on write mechanism or it is adviceable to put in place something at the application level?

Comment: Java String is immutable -- can't be changed after creation.  When you assign one String variable to another you're assigning a POINTER.  If one pointer is changed, all the other previously assigned pointer variables remain unchanged and still address the original String.  NO "copy on write" is done or required.

Comment: And this behavior is very definitely spelled out in the JVM spec.  Breaking this would cause enormous problems.

Comment: I thought that, like in other languages, that memory-saving was done thoruhg COW. Ok, now i understand that is obtained thorugh a pointer to an immutable object. I go back and correct the question.

Comment: While one can use String.intern to make identical Strings be replaced with a single copy, the use of that interface (other than in some system-defined situations) is entirely optional, meaning that two Strings with the same value are not necessarily the same String with the same address.  There can be an unlimited number of distinct Strings with a given value.

Answer (score 1):

Another aspect of this is that your Strings will not be the same if they are created dynamically (e.g. allocated by parser). Check out String.intern() if space is a concern:

```
String a = String.valueOf('a') + "b";
String b = a.intern();
String c = "ab";
// now b == c is true
```

Comment: `"ab"` is guaranteed to be interned already. You can also call `a.intern` rather than `String.intern(a)`.

Comment: ... not to mention that the compiler can merge `"a" + "b"` into `"ab"` to begin with, such that the `intern` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! Code now fits what I intended.

Answer (score 0):

as @Hot Licks said: strings are immutable so there is no place to talk about copy on write. also when you are using mutable object you have to be aware that 'copy on write' may not be available on your client's environment.

and another thing that may be very important when you create a lot of objects. each object contains a few bytes of header, pointers etc. if i remember correctly empty object is like 20 bytes or so. when you we are talking about a lot of objects containing properties it starts to be significant. be aware of that and when you **measure** that it is causing the problem then you have to do something at the application level (lightweight design pattern, using stream xml parser etc).

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that String are regular objects.

```
String a = "test";
String b = a;
```

Does exactly the same thing as:

```
StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer("test");
StringBuffer b = a;
```

that is: in both cases, b is a second reference to a, and this is not due to the immutability. 

**Immutability comes into play**
So, you always handle two pointers to the same data. Now, if the class is immutable, you can forget about it: nobody will change your data under your shoes not because you have a copy for your own, but because the shared copy is immutable. You can even think that you have a copy of the string, but actually a copy has never existed since String b = a; does what it does for each object: a copy of the only reference.